# Why does Loki look "sick" when he first arrives on Earth?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, the-avengers-2012

In the Avengers movie, why is Loki sweating and weak when he first arrives on Earth, in the SHIELD base?

Comment: I didn't notice that... Are you sure?

Comment: Didn't he look sick too when visited Thor in "Thor"?

Comment: just want to say, great topic, i had noticed this a bit but never stopped to really thing about its implication. kudos!

Answer (score 60):

**Loki is not sick when he gets to Earth. He is EXHAUSTED. He likely used a significant part of his magical energy and drove himself to exhaustion accessing the Tesseract/Cosmic Cube from the other side, opening a portal and getting himself to Earth.**

He is reaching across the Nine Realms to access an alien technology and opening a gateway between two distant locations, an outstanding achievement since he did not have any other power source besides himself. He has to later have Professor Erik Selvig build an entire power plant to house the mechanism to create a larger gateway.

[image: Loki arriving at the SHIELD base]

This explains why the Bifrost was such a necessary tool in bridging the Nine Realms. It would leave the Asgardians far too vulnerable to their enemies to travel between realms without it.

[image: The Bifrost]

It is clear that Loki is obviously fatigued and can barely managed to move once he is placed in the bed of the truck. It is only the Asgardian zeal for combat, his superiority of weapons and his centuries of fighting prowess that allows him to easily defeat the SHIELD agents in the facility in his reduced state. (Being bullet-proof doesn't hurt, either.)

Loki, being a powerful sorcerer, decided he would fall from the Bifrost and use his magic to find his way to other worlds among the Nine Realms of the World Tree. He was obviously successful finding not only a place where he could take refuge, but he even found allies in the Chitauri, who were willing to offer him an army in exchange for the opportunity to conquer Earth and steal the Tesseract/Cosmic Cube.

> Considering the end of the Avengers and the reveal that Thanos AND the Infinity Gauntlet were the secret enemy behind Loki's army, it is possible Loki's survival had less to do with his ability and more to do with Thanos needing a potential lackey to do his dirty work. With the power of the Infinity Gauntlet Thanos could have easily rescued Loki.

[image: Thanos from the "Thanos Imperative: Ignition Vol 1 #1" comic cover]

Comment: What about looking exhausted in Thor? And, is the Gautlet seen in the Movie?

Comment: I'd like to ask Thecafremo's question again : we do see Thanos in the post-credit scene, but do we really see the Gauntlet ?

Comment: @Kalissar this.  I don't remember there being any explicit mention of Loki's "boss", or this gauntlet thing.

Comment: @Kalissar -- yes, we see part of the gauntlet, see my answer for a discussion of the gem in Loki's spear; at acolyte -- the Chitari leader keeps reminding Loki about the one who gave him this power and opportunity, and Thor asks who put the scepter in Loki's hand (right before he fights Iron Man). Also, there may be part of the gauntlet in Avengers the whole time (see my answer below)

Comment: But... the gauntlet is useless without the Infinity Stones, which Thanos doesn't have yet. Or maybe he has one but not the rest?

Answer (score 12):

I definitely noticed that as well. He had prominent circles around his eyes, a sickly yellow color, and his voice was tired and weary. He stumbles when he is leading Hawkeye and the professor away to the Jeeps. When he moves into position into the Jeep's trunk, he practically falls into a sitting position. He has to lean heavily on the Jeep's railings as a support during the car chase. He seemed so very weak and sick, he looked as though he was dying- but he seems to get better. I'm not sure as to the origin of this pitiful state, but I can at least verify that your observation is correct- Loki was definitely weak and sweating when he appears on Earth. Perhaps it had something to do with the flashback of that alien touching the side of his head, but I'm not sure. He does say that he is

> "burdened with glorious purpose".

It could be that the journey through space, unprotected and without the aid of the Bifrost was strenuous even for his magic and abilities. He says later:

> With the Bifrost gone, how much dark energy did the Allfather have to muster to 
>   conjure you here, your precious Earth?

He probably had to pour a lot of himself into his own magic to journey, hence the weakened state upon arrival.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but it's actually "dark energy" not "black magic".

Answer (score 7):

**SPOILER ABOUT AFTER-CREDITS SCENE!!!!!

He Probably Looks Exhausted/Sick Becauase . . .**

Since Thanos is involved, I've often wondered if Loki's stone in his staff/spear is the Mind Gem, one of the Infinity/Soul Gems. Once marvel retconned them from all being "soul gems" (and all green, I think) to being different colored Infinity Gems, the Mind Gem was/is the blue shiny one. Think about it---it's blue, he controls folk's minds with it, he manipulates the Avengers with it on the Hellicarrier (or somehow the gem does when they're all arguing: *Dr. Banner, put down the spear*!!!

On the Infinity Gems: http://tinyurl.com/lmr64e2  ---   http://tinyurl.com/kmqey67

Okay so here's what I'm thinking:
The Gems have an organic relationship. They affect each other. As stated in the first link, and somewhat obvious, the power gem augments the mind gem. It is reasonable to posit that using the mind gem would be taxing for the user without also having the Power Gem as a source. You'll notice Loki is spry for a bit but is taxed again after using the gem/stone/spear (both as a weapon and to control Hawkeye and the Selvig (sp?) )

EDIT: I removed spoiler/hidden text b/c (A) a prior post already includes a pic of Thanos, and (B) Avengers has been out over a year now.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen it written in many places and in the comics that Thanos is one for torture. At the end of Thor, it appears that Loki really just wants to die. However, it is very likely that he was picked up by Thanos and then tortured by him to make him aid Thanos and the Other with the attack on earth due to Loki having access to the Vault on Asgard where the Infinity Gauntlet is kept. Both movies seem to be connected with this. If you look at the after credits scene of Thor, Loki looks like total sh**. His face has been burned severely, his eyes have circles engulfing them and his teeth have rotted greatly. He was obviously burned, which would be a form of torture that Thanos would subdue against a *frost* giant. Then, in the Avengers, Loki is ill and weak, nearly the whole way through. Many say Tom tripped when leaving SHIELD, but that is incorrect. Loki hunches over in pain as he is leaving, basically falls into the bed of the truck and is seen mostly sitting in the underground tunnels where his team was working. It is also obvious that the Other could inflict pain upon Loki just by touching him. I strongly believe that Loki was tortured by Thanos into helping him get the Tesseract and, eventually, the Gauntlet. Hopefully Marvel will explore it in Thor 3 or the Avengers 3. Fingers crossed that they do because I am really dying to know.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the strain of the magic taken to get him to Earth took its toll. Yet I can't help but think that the circles under his eyes look a lot like the ones under Clint's (Hawkeye) while he's under the mind control.

Answer (score 0):

Hé had the snake poison torture from the myth.

When you see the flashback and before the hand reached his face. You see a snake behind then.

Look up the myth... They worked that into the story with a twist.

Comment: A screenshot would make this much better.

Comment: Looking at the scene will tell you plus read the original Loki myth. Says it all actually seeing how his eyes look all dark. https://theavengers.tumblr.com/post/188415371470

Comment: https://www.storynory.com/the-punishment-of-loki/

Answer (score -1):

He was somewhat under the influence of the Tesseract, similar to Hawkeye and Selvig. Loki is not normally a very great guy, but in the Avengers he was not really himself.

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement?  I can't think of anything in the movie that would suggest this to be the case.

Comment: So, is he still under the influence of the Tessarect after *The Avengers*? He discusses his attempts to take over the Earth with no remorse and no mention of having ever been under anyone else's control.

Comment: You can tell by the look of his eyes when he first makes his appearance, he wasn't completely under the control of Thanos, just "somewhat" influenced. During the time between Thor and the Avengers, Loki was tortured and he was brainwashed to believe that freedom is a lie, which is what he passed on to the people he controlled with his scepter. He didn't show any remorse because he believes humans are lower than him, the same way the average human shows no remorse for stepping on an ant. Loki wanted to rule humans, but he was not the mastermind behind the whole invasion scheme.

Answer (score -1):

okay i'm thinking, it would be a pretty good "plot twist" if Loki was actually tortured by Thanos. first of all he is very silly and weak, and have dark "spots" under his eyes( much like Clint while he was under mind control) so my theory is that, Thanos tortured him, broke him down, and warped his mind so he could control him. thanos is known for his torture, but the only ones who can truly confirm this are the cast and crew,, but i hope deeply that they would confirm it in avengers or thor 3- personally i think that it would make great depth to Loki,and would make a lot of sense. It would actually explain a lot, anyways hope this helped:)

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this, or just think it's a cool theory?

Answer (score -2):

I saw an interesting theory about this actually. He was being tortured. Someone commented on how, as the movie progresses, Loki begins to look stronger and less sickly. Meaning wherever he came from caused his weakened form, a.k.a. Thanos and the Chitari.

They were torturing him to work with them, which I believe fits Loki's personality more than having him help them willingly. It could also explain the "burdened" part of "burdened with glorious purpose".

Later we see Loki being essentially bullied by the Other. He manages to cause Loki physical pain which we see later in the film isn't an easy task. Loki is shot by Coulson, fights Thor (who is obviously much stronger than him), and goes up against the Hulk and the only one who does enough damage to take him out is Hulk.

Personally, I believe this theory over the rest but the only ones who can confirm anything (cast and crew of the film) haven't said anything about it.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score -3):

I think he looked sick because... well, if people actually think about it, inside the studio it gets hot fast. 'trust me'. And because of his sweating, he was maybe just really warm. In one of his comments on a different site, it said test jumping in his suit is like jumping while wearing a 40 pound suit. So, hope this helps.