# Why was Loki affected by the bullets in this scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers-2012, loki

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/can-asgardians-deflect-human-weaponry-or-is-it-their-weapons-and-technology-that), within the scope of MCU and as well as in the comic books, Asgardians are quite resistant to bullets.

However, I was recently re-watching ***The Avengers (2012)*** movie and something caught my eye.

At the beginning, when the Tesseract opens the portal and Loki appears, the S.H.I.E.L.D agents start shooting him and he was completely unaffected by it. As a matter of fact, he seemed completely immune and the bullets simply *bounced off of him*. This, may well be plausible as Asgardian physiology is different from humans.

But when Loki and Hawkeye are leaving the premises, Loki, for a moment, is seen to be straining himself and show pain as if those bullets hurt him (*I can't put this into better words so I've added a video and a photo below to show it*).

[image]

In the video, pay attention at around the 3:30 ~ 3:40 minute mark.

So, how can Loki be hurt by the bullets if bullets don't affect him?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Asgardians deflect human weaponry or is it their weapons and technology that protects them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/can-asgardians-deflect-human-weaponry-or-is-it-their-weapons-and-technology-that)

Comment: @Edlothiad I saw that question (and it is the same) but the answer was based on the comic book representations of Thor. As i mentioned in the question,I'm looking for the MCU version of the characters.

Comment: And my question is mainly that if he was resistant, why was he limping around at the end of the scene (in the video)?

Comment: The question there is also about the MCU, disliking the answers is not a reason to ask a new question. You should provide a bounty asking for better answers.

Comment: Are we sure he was hurt by the bullets? I got the impression that making it to earth, through whatever means he managed it, caused a fair degree of physical strain.

Comment: @Edlothiad yes you are right. Anyways, i have changed the question to make more sense. if it is acceptable, le me know :)

Comment: It now seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16681/why-does-loki-look-sick-when-he-first-arrives-on-earth) (answer 2 in particular)

Comment: @Edlothiad can't argue with that, it is exactly what I was looking for. :) Thanks man!